# Division of integers returns 0

Tags: sql, postgresql, division

I feel like I'm missing something obvious. I am trying to test out the distribution of `random()`. Here is the table:

```
create table test (
  id int,
  random_float float,
  random_int int
);
```

Here is what I want to do:

```
truncate table test;
insert into test (id)
values (generate_series(1,1000));
update test 
set
  random_float = random() * 10 + 1;
update test
set
  random_int = trunc(random_float);
select 
  random_int,
  count(random_int) as Count,
  cast( count(random_int) / max(id) as float) as Percent
from test
group by random_int
order by random_int;
```

However, the "Percent" column returns zero for every record. I tried casting it as float, as decimal, I tried changing the `random_int` column to decimal instead of integer, always same result.

[Here is a fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/63252/14)

Any insight as to what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Cast to `numeric` (or `float`, though I prefer the former) *before* you divide.

Comment: You can reproduce this in one line: `select 1/2`. Returns 0.

Comment: @Phrancis, you should cast *before* you divide: `select 1/2, 1.0/2, 1.0*1/2, 1::numeric/2, cast(1 as float)/2;`

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You should cast before you divide, but also you were missing a subquery to get the total count from the table. [Here's the sample](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/63252/37).

```
select 
  random_int,
  count(random_int) as Count,
  cast(count(random_int) as decimal(7,2)) / cast((select count(random_int) from test) as decimal(7,2)) as Percent
from test
group by random_int
order by random_int;
```

Comment: I knew it had to be to do with casting, so thanks 6 years later still a helpful answer! In my case I was casting the entire calc as decimal(10,2) which yielded 0 but casting the individual components worked a treat. Still learning!

Comment: It is enough to cast one of the numbers (e.g. numerator), then the whole expression becomes decimal.

Answer (score 4):

Try this query instead:

```sql
select 
       random_int,
       count(random_int) as Count,
       cast( count(random_int) / max(id) as float) as Percent,
       (100.0 * count(random_int) / max(id))::numeric(5,2) as pct
  from test
 group by random_int
 order by random_int;
```

PostgreSQL has a strong types system. In your case, type is implied by `count()` function, which returns `bigint` (or `int8`) and `id` column, which is `integer`.

I would recommend using `100.0` as initial multiplier, that'll cause whole expression to be calculated as numeric and will also provide real percents. You might also want to cast to `numeric(5,2)` at the end to get rid of too big number.