# Summing to 2 decimal places in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, casting, sum, rounding

I have generated a report with totals in `SQL` and would like to get the result to 2 decimal places however, I am not managing.

I have tried several codes but still the sum is coming as a round to the nearest 10.

I have tried the following

```
cast (sum(Amount) as decimal(10,2))
convert(sum(Amount) as decimal(10,2))
```

Here is a sample of my code and what the expected figure should be:

```
select YYYMM, CustomerID, SUM(Amount) as TotalAmount
from (
   SELECT  a.subscriberid,yyymm
    ,sum(Amount)/(1024*1024*1024) as Amount
```

In the about it is only a snip of the coding and had to change some of the calculations due to data sensitivity

Current Output

```
YYYMM   CustomerID   TotalAmount
202010     1234           0
```

```
--Expected Output
YYYMM   CustomerID   TotalAmount
202010     1234           0.45
```

Can someone help me please? I am using the **Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio**

Comment: Instead of `sum(Amount)/(1024*1024*1024)` try `sum(Amount)/(1024.0*1024.0*1024.0)`. You might have some "integer math" going on earlier in your query.

Comment: Do these answer your question? [SQL Server, division returns zero](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1666407/2029983), [Division of integers returns 0](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26537140/2029983)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably, `amount` is an integer, and you are facing integer division. When both operands to a division are integers, SQL Server (and many other databases) generates an integer result: basically, `3/4` is `0`, not `0.75`.

You can force a decimal context by turning one of the operands to a decimal - then `cast()` the result:

```
cast(sum(amount) / (1024.0 * 1024 * 1024) as decimal(10, 2)) as total_amount
```